# How to Project or Reproject Map Using csv file data in R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, basemap

I have a csv file loaded in R as the follow example below. I trying to assign projection. Then, plot map and draw pie for species variable for each grid cell.

```
Month    long      lat  variable   value
3       48.0000 -12.8800 SKJTotal  10.990
3       47.8800 -13.0800 SKJTotal   5.127
3       48.0000 -13.0000 YFTTotal   4.576
3       48.0000 -13.0200 SKJTotal   4.240
5       42.6800 -12.5700 SKJTotal  10.838
5       41.8700 -11.4800 SKJTotal  13.615
5       45.3200 -14.6300 BETTotal  13.615
5       45.6800 -14.1300 SKJTotal  21.675
5       42.5500 -11.7200 SKJTotal   6.130
5       45.5000 -13.7000 BETTotal  43.350
5       41.7800 -11.6300 YFTTotal  74.878
```

I used the codes below to assin the projection.

```
coordinates(mpma) = ~long+lat # trying to assign the projection
proj4string(mpma) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
is.projected(mpma)
[1] FALSE
```

The summary from overall csv file this one below.

```
summary(mpma)
Object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min   max
long  34.00 49.35
lat  -27.33 -9.93
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
Number of points: 27054
Data attributes:
     variable        value         
 SKJTotal:9018   Min.   :  0.0000  
 YFTTotal:9018   1st Qu.:  0.0000  
 BETTotal:9018   Median :  0.4575  
                 Mean   :  6.1566  
                 3rd Qu.:  6.0000  
                 Max.   :412.4290
```

Then, I try to plot the map using normal plot as follow:

```
plot(mpma$long,mpma$lat)
map(add = T,fill=T,col="grey")
```

The returning map is not projected.

How do I fix the projection?

I have been tried many codes without success.  I also tried to use the world basemap setting the long=c(30,50) and lat=c(-30,-9). But here the output map as very small. And I can't find the code to zoom or increase the resolutions. I intend to draw grids and draw pies for each grid cells.

Comment: Use spTransform(mpma, _crs_proj4string_of_your_choice_)  - this *modifies* the coordinates. The *assignment* you do above is merely nominating the right coordinate system the data is currently in.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do:

```
plot(mpma$long,mpma$lat)
```

do

```
plot(mpma)
```

What you've done gets the long and lat values and plots them like they are any two vectors in R, like you were making a scatterplot. If you plot the *object* then R goes "Ooh, its a spatial object, I better treat it right" and sets up the axes correctly for a map.